# NxN matrix filled with random numbers 1-99

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying to create a square matrix filled with random numbers from 1 - 99. 
I have set this up, but anything over 7 dimensions returns an error, and I'm not sure why.

Every time I have started over the max dimensions it will break at is different.

```
package matrix;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import  java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {

static int dim;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String repeat="yes";
    do
        {if (dim<=25)
            {//prompt user for dimensions, only need one number
                System.out.println("Please enter the dimensions of the matrices. Enter       one number that is greater or equal to 25.");
                dim=sc.nextInt();
             //all rows and columns are equal
         matrices m1 = new matrices(dim);
         m1.randomFill();
         m1.printMatrix();

             System.out.print("\n Would you like to repeat the program? (yes/no)");
                repeat=sc.next();
            }
        else 
            {System.out.print("Invalid dimensions, pleasse enter a number greater or equal to 25.");
            dim=sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    while (repeat.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

    }

 }

public class pool {

//instance variables
private int size;
static int [] poolArray;
private Random ridx;

//constructors
public pool (int sz)
{size = sz;
poolArray = new int [sz];
ridx = new Random ();
}

//instance methods
public void fillPool ()
{for(int n=0; n<size; n++)
    {poolArray [n]=n+1;
    }
}

public int randomValue ()
    {int idx = ridx.nextInt(size);
    int rval = poolArray [idx];
    size--;
    poolArray [idx] = poolArray [size];
    return (rval);
    }    

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 pool p1 = new pool (99);
 {p1.fillPool ();}

 System.out.println(poolArray[0]+", "+poolArray[25]+", "+poolArray[98]);
 System.out.println(p1.randomValue());
}      
}
public class matrices {
static int [][] m;
static int size;
static pool p1 = new pool (99);
 {p1.fillPool ();}
static pool p2 = new pool (99);
 {p1.fillPool ();}

 matrices (int dimension)
 {m=new int [dimension][dimension];
 size=dimension;}

static void randomFill ()
 {int i, j; // loop counters
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
      { for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        m[i][j]=p1.randomValue();
          }
 }

   static void printMatrix()
{   int i, j;   // loop counters
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
      { for(j=0;j<size;j++)   
    System.out.print(m[i][j] + "  ");
    System.out.println("");    
  }
    System.out.println(""); 
}

}
```

This is the error that comes up:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive 
   at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300) at matrix.pool.randomValue(pool.java:34)        
   at matrix.matrices.randomFill(matrices.java:28) at matrix.Matrix.main(Matrix.java:30) Java     
   Result: 1
```

Comment: @radiodef   
Error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:300)
 at matrix.pool.randomValue(pool.java:34)
 at matrix.matrices.randomFill(matrices.java:28)
 at matrix.Matrix.main(Matrix.java:30)
        Java Result: 1

Comment: I'm sorry, obviously, I'm learning. I took the pool class from an assignment I had completed before (which worked perfectly) then I tried taking out the decrementing part (which was originally there to avoid repeat numbers), but then it was still giving me the errors, so I kept it in.

Comment: YOU FOUND THE PROBLEM! that was it I took it out again and it works fine. Thank you so much. I clearly needed fresh eyes to point out my stupid mistake. No to finish this. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Please, format your code!

But `rids.nextInt(size)` can throw an error if `size < 0`, which it indicates.
Subsequently this is possible if you have an `integer overflow`, where you are trying to store an integer `> Integer.MAX_VALUE`, **possibly** resulting in a negative value due to the overflow. This behaviour differs per integer.